# How to make a request file to be executed before another in WireMock?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-test, wiremock, web-api-testing

I have 2 json files for sending request:

First:

```
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "my/url/([url0-9/-]{13})",
    "queryParameters": {
      "type": {
        "equalTo": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
```

Second:

```
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/my/url/ID12345678",
    "queryParameters": {
      "type": {
        "equalTo": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
```

My case is the second file but the first file with regex is always executed before, so I can not have the expected response for my case. How can I make the second to be executed before the first so that when I send a certain ID it will have the response that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your specific use case, you could either use [Scenarios](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/#scenarios) or [Priority](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/#stub-priority). Making a few assumptions, I believe Priority will accomplish this with ease.

First

```json
{
  "priority": 5,
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "my/url/([url0-9/-]{13})",
    "queryParameters": {
      "type": {
        "equalTo": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second

```json
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/my/url/ID12345678",
    "queryParameters": {
      "type": {
        "equalTo": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Priority tells WireMock to check certain stubs/mappings before others. So, in this case, WireMock will check the second stub before the first, because it has a higher priority (lower number === higher priority). You could also omit adding a priority to the first mapping, as the default priority is 5.

Comment: That really helps. Thank you for your answer.